# linked list of objects without duplicates (C++)?

Tags: c++, list, templates, linked-list, duplicates

I've developed a simple template linked list.. my method for add an object is this:

```
void add(T *obj) {
    Node *n = new Node;
    T *copy = new T(*obj);
    n->info = copy;
    [...]
```

where my Node is a struct:

```
struct Node {
    T* data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
Node *head;
```

How can I do a method to see if an object was already added? (Because I don't want duplicates)

This is a template, so the only solution that I've thinked it's control if a node already points the object (viewing memory address passed in add method and searching it into a node).. but the add method, do a copy of the object and inserts it into a new node, so this solution don't work

I've thinked to use a list of T pointer and insert the address of object every time I add a new object in add method but I can't use standard list (because this is an homework) and I can't use my class because it's not defined yet.. (g++ don't compile)

If I use a private pointer in the class, that point the last object added this work if I try to add the same object twice consecutively.. but if I add another object and then add the same, the list will add the object

some ideas?

Another short question:
is it right the copy in add method? or this copy can do a strange memory crash? (I'm new to C++)

Thanks all for your patience :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Were you really asked to write a list class that prevents duplicate inserts? That seems obscure. 
One way is to keep track of the first element in the list and scan the whole list during each insert.
It's not clear what the requirements are but copying seems wrong to me.

Comment: The simplest way would be to walk through the list before you add a new item, checking to see if one of the nodes already has it.

Comment: If you will be doing check for duplicates I would recommend you implement a hash_map.

Comment: @AdamLiss: yes, but this is always false, because each node point to a copy of the object passed in add method, how can I compare objects? First, I've thinked using address but isn't usefull because copies have others memory address.. if you have some ideas, could you write an example, please?
andre: I can't use hash_map
JohanLundberg: why copy is wrong? what is the correct copy?
Thanks

Comment: ok, maybe I can resolve with an overload of operator ==